# Test suite result dependency in testNG

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testng, suite, testng.xml

I have test suite xml file  that contains other test suites in the following format:

```
<suite-files>
    <suite-file path="debug1.xml" />
    <suite-file path="debug2.xml"/>

</suite-files>
```

Is there a way to add a dependency between the two sub suites? Meaning if `debug1.xml` fails, then `debug2.xml` should not be executed at all.
TestNG does not provide any dependency on the `<suite-files>` level. Can this be done, perhaps, through some listener?

Answer (score 1):

You can define [TestNG groups](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups) in your test code and [arrange the dependencies](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-in-xml)like:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="test">

    <groups>
        <dependencies>
            <group name="debug1" depends-on=""/>
            <group name="debug2" depends-on="debug1"/>
        </dependencies>
    </groups>
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="debug1.xml"/>
        <suite-file path="debug2.xml"/>
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

References:

- [TestNG XML](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml)
- [TestNG](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/TestNG)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but the above xml snippet, is not a valid one, since you cannot have groups and suite-files. Furthermore, grouping seems not to be running in parallel mode, and dependency didn't work correctly for me.Additionally I prefer to organise my tests in suites, and not tag them, by group name. More maintainability for me that way. Any other ideas?